# c# wpf vertical line next to listviewitem on click

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem

I'm trying to achieve something like that of this in the below image. On click of an item of `ListViewItem`, I need that vertical line to place just before the list view item. But doesn't work! When I click on the item, it pushes the entire list downwards as per the calculation.

[image: Vertical line image]

**What I did**:

```
**Code behind**:

    private void LV_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = LV.SelectedIndex;
        MoveCursorMenu(index);
    }

    private void MoveCursorMenu(int index)
    {
        GridCursor.Margin = new Thickness(0, (14 + (46 * index)), 0, 0);
    }

**XAML code:**

   <!-- Navigation panel -->
        <Grid x:Name="nav_pnl" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Width="65" Background="#2E333A">

            <StackPanel x:Name="st_pnl">

    <Grid x:Name="GridCursor" Width="3" Height="46" Background="#0096D6"
                      Margin="0 14 0 0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                <!-- List view with menu list items -->
                <ListView x:Name="LV" Margin="0 14"
                                  Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                  SelectionChanged="LV_SelectionChanged">

                    <!-- Home -->
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,15" MouseEnter="ListViewItem_MouseEnter">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="230">

                            <Image Source="Assets/home.png" Stretch="None"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="Home" Margin="25,0,0,0"
                                               Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                        <!-- Tooltip for Home -->
                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_home" Content="Home"
                                             Style="{StaticResource tt_style}" />
                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>


                    </ListViewItem>

                    <!-- Contacts -->
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,15" MouseEnter="ListViewItem_MouseEnter">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="230">

                            <Image Source="Assets/contacts.png" Stretch="None"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="Merger" Margin="25,0,0,0"
                                               Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                        <!-- Tooltip for contacts -->
                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_contacts" Content="Contacts"
                                             Style="{StaticResource tt_style}" />
                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                    </ListViewItem>
           </ListView>
      </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone push me into the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should implement the visual effect in the `ItemTemplate` rather than trying to push the margins in the code-behind. Bind to the `IsSelected` property to determine whether an item is selected.